# Can I redefine an environment?

Tags: beamer, xetex, frame

I want to redefine `frame` like this:

```
\renewenvironment{frame}{
    \begin{frame}{\bfseries{\sectiontitle}}
}{
    \end{frame}
}
```

Then I can:

```
\section{My section}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        this section
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

But it produces an error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\str_if_eq:nnTF ...\__str_if_eq:nn {\exp_not:n {#1
                                                  }}{\exp_not:n {#2}}=0\exp_...
l.49 \begin{frame}

No pages of output.
```

Comment: You cannot define an environment that already exist using the same env, that leads to a circular definition.

Comment: Try reading doc of xpatchcmd and use it [formatting - Redefining proof environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251248/redefining-proof-environment)

Comment: Or just backup it [etoolbox - Modifying an existing environment, but keeping the name - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291235/modifying-an-existing-environment-but-keeping-the-name)

Comment: It has another error of `Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \sectiontitle ` So how to **use section name as frame title**?

Comment: `frame` in beamer is a very special enviornment with highly specialised syntax and behaviour. While technically it's always possible to redefine anything I'd say the chance that a redefinition of `frame` does not break somthing is very small. Don't do this unless you are very familiar with all of beamer's source internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an example in page 60 from `beameruserguide`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{slide}
{\begin{frame}[environment=slide]
    \frametitle{\insertsection}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{slide}
Text
\end{slide}

\begin{slide}
\framesubtitle{another slide}
Text text
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @1900011604     I've missunterstood the question.

Comment: @1900011604 I think this new answer can help

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want to do, assuming you *don't* want to use a different environment name, would be not to use the frametitle at all, but just use the headline, which you can add/redefine with `\setbeamertemplate` along with `\insertsection`; unless you're using the headline for something else already (in which case you could add to it).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\vspace*{1cm}\hspace*{1cm}\Large\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\insertsection}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}
This slide is in the first section.
\end{frame}
\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}
Now in second section.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Still in second section.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer-headline-example]